# Will Google Analytics Work with no js script and only cookies

Tags: django, google-analytics

I have a django website which already has google analytics intgrated. Recently I implemented the cookie consent from user manually. Will the analytics work if I exclude the script(based on consent) from the html and cookies already exists in the users browser ?

Answer (score 0):

No. If the analytics script does not load, it will not collect analytics data whatsoever, because GA relies on Javascript events to track user behavior.

If you wanted to go a step further, you could also have a revocation of consent delete the GA cookies.